# Omit rows error

Tags: r

I would like to omit rows in a data frame that have NA in a specific column(y).
I am using `df<- [!is.na (df$y), ]`
This gets me: *Error: unexpected '[' in "df<- ["*
I have tried `df<- [(!is.na (df$y)), ]` with the same error. Could somebody help me figure out what is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: what about a simple `na.omit(youData)` ?

Comment: Op asks for a *specific* column on which to subset. Try `subset(DF, !is.na(y))`, but this questions has to be somewhere else

Comment: You need to put the name of the thing you're subsetting in front of the subset operator: `df<- df[!is.na(df$y), ]`

Comment: Maybe I am silly, if so there must be a link that can solve my doubts but it is not the same results with `na.omit` and subsetting in order to remove `na`?

Comment: @SabDeM Try it with `df<-data.frame(x=c(1,NA), y=c(NA,2))`. The `na.omit` option will drop both rows, the column specific `is.na` will only drop one row.

Comment: Aaron Katch, I did find this solution on forum. It was referring probably to a vector that is why it did not work on a data frame. So the MrFlick's suggestion worked well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank very much. I missed this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use na.omit as follows to remove all rows that have NA's regardless of the column:

```
df <- na.omit(df)
```

If you only want to remove rows from the dataframe relating to NA's in a specific column use the following:

```
df <- df[!(is.na(df$y)),]
```

You almost had it with second code segment but you need to move the exclamation mark outside the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `subset` function.

```
subset(DF, !is.na(y))
```

If you are using a `data.frame`, then `DF` may have empty levels after subsetting; unused levels are not automatically removed. See `droplevels` for a way to drop all unused levels from a data frame.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. Your answer seems even easier to implement. Will keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% filter(!is.na(y))
```

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df <- df[!is.na(y), ]
```

As @Arun has commented, in `data.table` v1.9.5+ you can use `na.omit(dt, cols="y")`

Comment: within data.table , you should avoid assign , simply `setDT(df)[!is.na(y)]`

Comment: In v1.9.5+, you can do: `na.omit(dt, cols="y")`.